# Accidentally deleted grub partition

Tags: grub2

I deleted the partition responsible for boot loading to the OS. And going forward when I start my PC up it only loops. Is there any link or procedure that can help me recover the partition or re-install GRUB

Comment: What partition did you delete exactly? Do you still have `/boot` and does it still contain `initrd.img*` and `vmlinuz*` and `initramfs*` files?

Comment: @terdon i think he deleted a separate grub partition which contains `.efi` files.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, that's what I want to check.

Comment: The partition i deleted was linuxswap (i believe thats the name of the partition)

Comment: linux swap? don't worry about that.

Comment: I have managed to create a live CD of the linux iso file on a USB, but now this is the error I get when I attempt to install it: Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool to repair GRUB. Here is its documentation : [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If you have delete your linux-swap partition, boot on a live-CD, open `gparted` (or install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted` and open it).

In gparted, recreate a partition (type `linux-swap`), apply, and reboot.

Comment: How big would you set this partition to?

Comment: Same size as your RAM size (I have 4GB of RAM, my swap size is 4GB)